# Tkinter Label wont appear inside Labelframe

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a GUI to accept 2 JSON files and compare them. As shown in the code below, my Labelframe(policyframe) is inside a second_frame used to create a scrollbar.

When running the code, I am successfully able to see the Label containing 'Name 1' and 'Name 2' from file 1 & 2 respectively. however, after creating the Label to display the description of the second file, a new window pops up displaying a blank screen.

In different trial & error these were my observations :

- I tried displaying other keys of File 1 and was able to see them also.
- Tried displaying the 'Name key' of both JSON files and was a success.
- Unable to see any other key of File 2 except the 'name_c'

Have also added the json data for example.

```
from typing import Counter
from file import Root
from io import SEEK_CUR
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

import json

class Main:
    def __init__(gui, master):
        label1 = Label(second_frame, text = "Test GUI")
        label1.pack()
        button_a = Button(second_frame, text="Choose Json File1", command=gui.file_a)
        button_a.pack()
        button_c = Button(second_frame, text="Choose Json File2", command=gui.file_c)
        button_c.pack()

        button_compare = Button(second_frame, text="Compare Json", command=gui.compare).pack()

    def file_a(gui) :
        gui.filename1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select a file", filetype = (("json", "*.json"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
        
    def file_c(gui) :
        gui.filename2 = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select a file", filetype = (("json", "*.json"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    
    def compare(gui) :
        Label(second_frame, text = "Starting to Compare").pack()

        with open(gui.filename1) as af:
            data_a = json.load(af)

        with open(gui.filename2) as cf:
            data_c = json.load(cf)
        
        count = 0

        for f1 in data_a['policies'] :
            name_a = f1['displayName']
           
            for f2 in data_c['rules'] :
                name_c = f2['properties']['displayName']
                description_c = f2['properties']['description']

                if name_a == name_c:
                    
                    policy_frame = LabelFrame(second_frame, text='Comparing Json Files', padx=5, pady=5)
                    policy_frame.pack()

                    Label(policy_frame, text=f'Name 1 : {name_a}').pack()
                    
                    Label(policy_frame, text=f'Name 2 : {name_c}').pack()
                    #Label(policy_frame, text=f'Description 2 : {description_c}').pack()
               
                else :
                    count = count + 1
                    
        print(count)                

root = Tk()

root.title("Test GUI")
root.geometry("500x400")

main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
my_canvas.pack (side = LEFT, fill = BOTH, expand=1)

my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = my_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))

second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)

my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")

main = Main(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Json File 1

```json
{
  "policies": [
    {
      "displayName": "Name 1",
      "status": {
        "cause": abc,
        "code": "python",
        "description": Test 1
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

Json File 1

```json
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "displayName": "File 2 Name 1",
      "description": "Description of Key 1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is actually being displayed, only the thing is the `labelFrame` size is being altered which is why i was seeing a blank screen.

Simply by packing the Label to anchor on west, the data was visible.

`labelname.pack(padx=5, pady=5, anchor = "w"`

This solves up the issue.